# React + TypeScript: Scroll event type not assignable to window.addEventListener

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, events

Can it be that TypeScript DOM types for events and React Event types don't go well with another?

Look at this code:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const onScroll = (event: React.ChangeEvent<Body>) => {
      console.log("event", event.target);
    };

    window.addEventListener("scroll", onScroll);

    return () => window.removeEventListener("scroll", onScroll);
  }, []);
```

It throws

```
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 2, '(type: "scroll", listener: (this: Window, ev: Event) => any, options?: boolean | AddEventListenerOptions | undefined): void', gave the following error.
    Argument of type '(event: ChangeEvent<Body>) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(this: Window, ev: Event) => any'.
      Types of parameters 'event' and 'ev' are incompatible.
        Type 'Event' is not assignable to type 'ChangeEvent<Body>'.
```

Than I tried the following. This compiles correctly.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const onScroll = (event: Event) => { // <--- changed event type here
      console.log("event", event.target);
    };

    window.addEventListener("scroll", onScroll);

    return () => window.removeEventListener("scroll", onScroll);
  }, []);
```

`event.target` can not be access without compile errors, though. I checked the following function call (it is working in the browser if I ts-ignore the error):

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const onScroll = (event: Event) => {
      console.log(
        "event",
        event?.target?.activeElement.getBoundingClientRect() // <--- this function call is actually working (ts-ignored it), even if TypeScript throws an error
      );
    };

    window.addEventListener("scroll", onScroll);

    return () => window.removeEventListener("scroll", onScroll);
  }, []);
```

throws

```
TypeScript error in /home/sirhennihau/Workspace/giphy-search/src/Components/grid.tsx(27,24):
Property 'activeElement' does not exist on type 'EventTarget'.  TS2339

    25 |       console.log(
    26 |         "event",
  > 27 |         event?.target?.activeElement.getBoundingClientRect()
       |                        ^
    28 |       );
    29 |     };
    30 |
```

My dependencies:

```
    "@types/node": "^12.0.0",
    "@types/react": "^16.9.53",
    "@types/react-dom": "^17.0.0",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.1",
    "typescript": "^4.0.3"
```

Are maybe just the typings bad or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 10):

Well, yes, React-Events and DOM-Events *sometimes* don't "go well" with one another, but there are clean ways to handle your use case (and most of all use cases in React, in my experience):

#### DOM events

The DOM methond `window.addEventListener` expects a DOM-`EventListener` (
`(evt: Event): void;`), so you need to use the DOM-`Event` interface (as you did).

Here I added some types to your code to illustrate this:

```
useEffect(() => {
    const onScroll: EventListener = (event: Event) => { // <-- DOM-EventListener
        console.log("event", event.target);
    };

    const win: Window = window;   // <-- DOM-Window, extends DOM-EventTarget
    win.addEventListener("scroll", onScroll);

    return () => window.removeEventListener("scroll", onScroll);
}, []);
```

#### `event.target`

The `event.target` should be accessible.
I assume you mean that you get errors if you try to acces `event.target.activeElement`.

`event.target.activeElement` **throws an error**, because `Event` *could* be any event,
`event.target` *could* be any element that extends `EventTarget | null`,
which is no specific element, and *maybe* has no `activeElement`.

**But it works** despite of the TS error, because in reality it is an element that *has* the `.activeElement`.

```
const onScroll: EventListener = (event: Event) => {
    const targetAny: EventTarget | null = event.target; // <-- maybe has no .activeElement
    console.log( targetAny.activeElement );
};
```

If you are sure what the element is, you might [type assert](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions)
the specific element:

```
const onScroll: EventListener = (event: Event) => {
    const targetDiv: HTMLDocument = event.target as HTMLDocument; // <-- assert DOM-HTMLDocument
    console.log("DOM event", targetDiv.activeElement);    // <-- activeElement works
};
```

#### React events

The React-Types should be used with React-Elements.

You **still would have to assert** the type of `event.target` to access the properties of a specific element (here I use `.style`), because the `.target` of the `React.SyntheticEvent` (which extends `React.BaseSyntheticEvent`) is exactly the same DOM-`EventTarget` as the DOM-`Event` uses.

To be clear: yes, React also uses some DOM-Types, so here React "goes well" with DOM-Events.

```
const onScrollReact: React.EventHandler<React.UIEvent<ReactNode>> = (event: React.UIEvent<React.ReactNode> ) => {
    const target: EventTarget = event.target;     // <-- React uses the DOM EventTarget
    const targetDiv: HTMLDivElement = target as HTMLDivElement; // <-- type assert DOM-HTMLDivElement
    console.log("React event", target.style);     // <-- throws TS error
    console.log("React event", targetDiv.style);  // <-- no TS error
};

return (<div
    onScroll={ onScrollReact }
    style={{ height: '400px', overflow: 'scroll' }}
>
    <div style={{ height: '2000px', backgroundColor: '#eee' }}>
        try scroll event
    </div>
</div>);
```

You could alternatively use the DOM-`HTMLDivElement` in this example (the behavior is exactly the same, but it is more 'declarative', I guess):

```
const onScrollReact2: React.EventHandler<React.UIEvent<HTMLDivElement>> = (event: React.UIEvent<HTMLDivElement>) => {
    console.log("React event", event.target.style); // <-- still throws TS error
};
```